# MySQL Repeating Operation for each row of a table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to update the value of a column in MySQL for all the values present in another table, but when I try to do this, I get the following error. How can I achieve this?

```
 update table1 set value = "0" where url = (select * from url_list) ; 
 ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "IN" for "=" operator or

```
(select * from url_list)
```

query should return only one row.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the value set to 0 if the url exists in the url column of url_list, try

```
update table1 set value = "0" where url in (select url from url_list);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you change the `=` to `IN`:

```
update table1 set value = "0" where url IN (select * from url_list);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update table1 set value = "0" where url IN (select * from url_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the end of your query:

```
WHERE url IN (select url from url_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table1 x
  JOIN url_list y
    ON y.url = x.url
   SET x.value = 0;
```

Comment: Your answer would be considerably better if you could explain _why_ you think this answers the question.

Comment: I (hope and) suspect that the OP wants to know how to update rows in one table that correspond to rows in another. This is the correct way to do it. As a rule (and all rules are there to be broken), never use IN where JOIN will do.